# Issue with angular-ui-router and $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

So I have used ui-router in my web page. So far I have two views: list of users, and profile of the user.

I created following states:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home"); 
//
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "index.html",
        controller: "View1Ctrl"
    })
    .state('profile', {
        url: "/profile/:user",
        templateUrl: "profile/profile.html",
        controller: "ProfileCtrl",
        params : { user: null }
    })
});
```

My module includes:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.router',
'myApp.home',
'myApp.profile',
])
```

And the Controller which throws an error:

```
ngular.module('myApp.profile' ,['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])


.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($stateProvider) {
        console.log($stateProvider.params);
    });
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">tateProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20ProfileCtrl
```

So: do you have any ideas where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to access the params? You should be doing

`$stateParams.user` for `/profile/:user` and pass in `$stateParams` instead of `$stateProvider` in your controller.

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was totally it. I need a break :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `$stateParams` in `myApp.profile` module you should include `ui.router` in it, instead of `ngRoute` module.

```
angular.module('myApp.profile' ,['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was tired and didn't realized I needed stateParams ;)